# Jquery text issue in tinymcs

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I have a simple issue,i have a textarea to which i assign text in jquery.This is plain text with some line spaces etc.here is an example of text

```
Brand new!!!

Huge size of 3 bedroom apartment located in Dubai Marina Orra tower for rent

Situated on high floor, overlooking a gorgeous view of Marina
```

Now when i assign to textarea,it is as same as above.here is code how i assign

```
$("#description").val(val);//val is above text
```

Now when i apply tinymce,it become like this

```
Brand new!!! Huge size of 3 bedroom apartment located in Dubai Marina Orra tower for rent Situated on high floor, overlooking a gorgeous view of Marina
```

spaces line breaks everything lost.
here is my code for tinymce

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('#description').tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : 'application/views/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
        // General options
        width : "830",
        height: "300",
        theme : "advanced",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,bullist,numlist,",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        gecko_spellcheck : true,  
        forced_root_block : '', // Needed for 3.x

        plugins : "paste"


    });
});
```

why my text disforms?[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sVs7X/1/)

Comment: Did you try: `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('HTML')` ?

Comment: i did not get any answer till now...what could be the issue with

Comment: Well, if you set value direct within `.val()` tinymce will not parse it.

Comment: its not working at any situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jsFiddle you attached tinyMCE after JQuery. It didn't work, I've fixed.
http://jsfiddle.net/sVs7X/3/

As you see the issue in a comments was right. Core of your trouble – `\n` newline symbol to `<br \>` conversion. You can do it by yourself replacing this:

```
$("#description").val(val)
```

to this:

```
$("#description").val( val.replace( /\n/, '<br />' ) );
```